# Rails Routing Issue, No Route Matches for Actions I defined in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So I am working through a book on Rails development right now, and I have run into a problem.  I have a "Users" controller with a few actions.  One of the actions I have defined in it is "follow"  However, whenever I have tried to link to that in my view with the rails helper, it tells me that I do not have that route defined.   Here is what my controller looks like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController   
def follow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.follow!(@user)
        redirect_to @user, notice: "Follow successful!"
    else 
        redirect_to @user, alert: "Error following."
    end
end
```

I have tried linking to this in two ways.  Here is the first:

```
<%= link_to "Follow", {action: 'follow'}, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

this produces the error: "No route matches {:action=>"follow", :controller=>"users", :id=>"2"}"

Here is the second way:

```
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(@user), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

this produces the message : "undefined method `follow_user_path' for #<#:0x007f8fb76bd570>"

even when i run rake routes, the path does not show up there, even though i have defined in my routes.rb file

```
resources :users
```

I am at a complete loss right now.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined the routes. `resources :users` will only define RESTful routes which won't cover `follow`. To cover that, you can write it like this:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :follow
  end
end
```

It'll generate URLs like:

```
/users/USER_ID/follow
```

Then from view, you can link to it like this:

```
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(USER_ID), class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Be sure to replace `USER_ID` with an actual user id!

Comment: that did it.  I was under the impression that if you defined an action in your controller, the route would be generated for it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

From my understanding, looks like there's no follow route, so inside your routes.rb, you'll need to put something like this:
get "/follow", to: "users#follow"